# Mount internal drive in Ubuntu LiveCD-Mount Error

Tags: mount, live-cd, data-recovery

I am trying to access my disk in an Ubuntu LiveCD. I cannot see my disk in nautilus and am trying to mount it.

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

gets this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 80.0 GB, 80026361856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9729 cylinders, total 156301488 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0007c70c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   147937279    73967616   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       147939326   156301311     4180993    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       147939328   156301311     4180992   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 1999 MB, 1999634432 bytes
16 heads, 32 sectors/track, 7628 cylinders, total 3905536 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        8064     3905535     1948736    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Then:

```
dmesg | grep disk
```

gets:

```
[    5.522888] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    8.579151] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I tried:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/disk
```

But I get this error:

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

What do I do? Thank you in advance.

Edit:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt/disk
```

gets:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

So I tried:

```
dmesg | tail
```

it gets:

```
[ 2812.431548] SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on sda5
[ 2812.432671] XFS (sda5): bad magic number
[ 2812.432688] XFS (sda5): SB validate failed with error 22.
[ 2812.539235] NTFS driver 2.1.30 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
[ 2812.563827] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered.
[ 2829.043992] systemd-hostnamed[18714]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed.
 Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install
nss-myhostname!
[ 3083.379348] EXT4-fs (sda1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 3096.843383] EXT4-fs (sda1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 3141.671012] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
[ 3328.134796] EXT4-fs (sda1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

Edit 2: Trying ext4 and ext3 gets me the same results:

```
sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sda1 /mnt/disk
```

So does /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda5

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /mnt/disk
sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sda2 /mnt/disk

sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /mnt/disk
sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sda2 /mnt/disk
```

Edit 3: It's been a while now, I'm going to send the computer to a repair shop soon. What should I do. I've been trying to mount it from a friend's system. No success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took it to a shop, it was fixed.